# Question about bug lifecycle

Tags: bugzilla

I need to calculate how much time was spent on a bug. I saw a bug lifecycle diagram, but it's not clear when someone starts working on the bug: after UNCONFIRMED or NEW or when ASSIGNED. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually at ASSIGNED. Although somebody has to do some work in order to move it from UNCONFIRMED to NEW--usually a "triager" who may be the developer or a QA person (or may even be a separate person).

In Bugzilla 4.0 we changed the default name of the ASSIGNED status to IN_PROGRESS which is a bit clearer.

-Max

Comment: Thank you. I thought to use the assignee field, but when I create a new bug, someone is assigned by default, so it's not an option too... Moreover, a bug can go directly from UNCONFIRMED or NEW to CLOSED.

Comment: Max, what's about work_time? I saw this field in documentation, but I cannot find it in API... Is it present?